# Cookie section not included in request headers (MERN APP)

Tags: authentication, cookies, authorization, mern

In the frontend, in case of get req /api/v1/users/chats it's request headers section-

```
GET /api/v1/users/chats HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

and in case of post req /api/v1/prompts/create that is -

```
POST /api/v1/prompts/create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------155569911418215713223055054392
Content-Length: 10637
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY1YzlmNzliNjlmNGQ4OTJkZjc4OSIsImlhdCI6MTwMTk2NywiZXhwIjoxNzA5MjA2NzY3fQ.ZQHlb8eL5MfArxTwJBKxFpI764W_VipAmNN4NMkPwIQ
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

then why am i facing the problem of not getting cookie part in the req header of /chats endpoint?
I am getting perfect results in the postman. Both of those paths use "isAuthorized" middleware. In client side i am getting error not authorized for "/api/v1/users/chats" but the other path is perfectly working since its getting cookies in its request header

In client side, the "get /api/v1/users/chats" path must run as expected and there must be a cookie section in the request header, just like "post /prompts/create" path